# Cloud not contact ROS master at http://172.20.10.3:1131x

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to remote PC to control the AGV (Raspberry PI )  but I have a problem
appear error "Cloud not contact ROS master at [http://172.20.10.3:1131x"](http://172.20.10.3:1131x%22)
PC and Raspberry Pi can connected  by use command " Ping  http://172.20.1x.2:11311 (On PC) " and
"Ping 172.20.1x.7 ( On PI ) .

Relate Information
Raspberry PI(Master) : 172.20.1x.2
Remote PC : 172.20.1x.7
Package on PC : Neotic
Package on Raspberry PI : Neotic
File .brashrc on PC :export  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.20.1x.2:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=172.20.1x.7
File .brashrc on PI :export  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.20.1x.2:11311
export  ROS_HOSTNAME=172.20.1x.2

Command that I use ( On PC )
-export  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.20.1x.2:11311
-export  ROS_HOSTNAME=172.20.1x.7
-rosrun rviz rviz

Thank you  , Sorry for grammar mistake . I am foreigner .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394042/cloud-not-contact-ros-master-at-http://172.20.10.3:1131x/) by [magnetRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/93243/magnetros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2022-01-14**:
You are running ROS master on the Raspberry PI and executing commands from the PC, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the name of the environment variable you are setting is wrong.

You may be able to connect by replacing HOSTNAME with ROS_HOSTNAME and MASTER_URI with ROS_MASTER_URI.

https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2FROS_HOSTNAME
https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_MASTER_URI

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [magnetRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/93243/magnetros/) on 2022-01-13**:
I changed already that still not working ,It same appear message above . Sir ,Thank you for reply .